# How to use similar label-for in different form elements, as "id" is unique in HTML standard?

Tags: html, standards, web-standards

In HTML standards;

- 2 same `name` attributes can be used in different `form` elements in the same html document.
- `id` attribute has to be uniqure in the same html document.
- `label for` requires `id` to work

**So, the following is valid**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form id="form1">
      <input name="abc">
    </form>
    <form id="form2">
      <input name="abc">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**However, the following is invalid if I use** `label for`** because id is not unique**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form id="form1">
      <label for="item">Click me</label>
      <input name="item" id="item">
    </form>
    <form id="form2">
      <label for="item">Click me</label>
      <input name="item" id="item">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

So, do I use `label for` incorrectly or is this a bug related to `label for` in standards?

Comment: What is the problem? As you say, `id` attribute values must be unique, so you simply have to use different values for different elements, whether they are in the same form or not.

Answer (score -1):

You are only supposed to have a unique id for every selector on a webpage.
Why? For starters, the id field is so you can hyperlink to the exact section of a page.
you can have multiple classes but only 1 id with a particular name.

I think what you are looking for is value=""  http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp